# Is it possible to forward requests from a Mac to a network adapter on an iPhone over USB?

Tags: networking, mac, usb, iphone, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPhone, with a VPN running on a network adaptor `utun1`. Is it possible to, from a Macbook, over USB, use this network adaptor and tunnel all traffic through it?

Comment: The question is incomplete. Please complete.

Comment: Page reloaded while I was editing, now fixed @Mikko